# change the name file putting the first line of my file C++ & Qt

Tags: c++, file, qt

I want to change the name of my file but I don't know how to do it. I have a .txt with words in two lines,and like to take the first line same as name of my file .txt.

This is my code:

```
void ventana1::on_ButtonGuardar_clicked()
{

QDir directory("C:/Users/Jaime/Desktop/interfaz/pacientes");
QString mFilename = directory.filePath("paciente.txt");

    QFile sFile(mFilename);
    if(sFile.open(QFile::WriteOnly | QFile::Text))
    {
        QTextStream out(&sFile);

        out << ui.lineEdit_2->text()<< "\n"
        << ui.lineEdit->text();

        sFile.flush();
        sFile.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You want to change the filename after writing to the file? Or you want to put the file's name as text into the file?

Comment: Do you want `ui.lineEdit_2->text()` to be the name of your file ?

Comment: I have two box of text where i can write, later I pulse a button save and create the file, but this file must have the word of the first box.

Comment: Yes Kevin, i want the content

Comment: Can you edit your post to contain an example? The example should answer the following questions: What text is in `lineEdit_2` and `lineEdit`? What should be the file name? What should be inside the file?

Comment: Yes, you can edit the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply replace

`QString mFilename = directory.filePath("paciente.txt");`

by

`QString mFilename = directory.filePath(ui.lineEdit_2->text());`

if you need to have the content of your lineEdit as your filename.